# What is the appropriate way to get notified on DFS junction mount in smb server on Mac OS?

Tags: swift, xcode, mount, smb, microsoft-distributed-file-system

When smb volume is mounted, we are getting notification in didMount event callback of `NSWorkspace`. Same is not consistent for `DFS` volume mount on browse. Is there a way to detect `DFS` junction mount on browse of smb shares?

We are watching for `DFS` target mounted on smb volume using NSWorkSpace’s `NSWorkspaceDidMountNotification` notification in our code. But didMount notification is inconsistent and not reliable. Only for the first time, didMount notification is notified. Later on we are not getting notified with didMount notification, though notification is successful.

Is there any other better approach to be notified on `DFS` junction mount?

Code snippet:

```
let workspace = NSWorkspace.shared
        workspace.notificationCenter.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(didMount(_:)) , name: NSWorkspace.didMountNotification, object: nil)

@objc func didMount(_ notification: NSNotification)  {
        NSLog("didMount, mounted userinfo - '%@'.", notification.userInfo!)
}
```

Expecting some way to get notified on `DFS` junction mount